# ВКонтакте - Сформировать ссылку на фотографию в альбоме

Tags: api, вконтакте

Отправляю на стену группы `ВКонтакте` фотографии с помощью `API` и необходимо сформировать ссылки вида

`https://vk.com/photo-161661030_456239019`

Где `161661030` это `ID` группы, но что такое `456239019`?
Это число не совпадает с `ID` фото возвращаемого `photos.saveWallPhoto` или `photos.getById`.

Comment: Это число появится после того, как вы запостите фото на стену с помощью `wall.post`, а для того, чтобы его запостить, берите owner_id и id из `photos.saveWallPhoto` (обратите внимание, что owner_id не должен и не будет совпадать с id группы)

Comment: Где оно появится? Как его достать? `ID` поста, которое возвращает `wall.post`, не совпадает с этим числом.

Comment: Зато прикрепление в этом посте уже будет совпадать

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. `wall.getById` возвращает "правильный" `ID`.